# Accessing fields on[2-9]/os[2-9]/L_OPTIONSNAME[2-9]/L_OPTIONSVALUE[2-9] through API

Tags: paypal

I can successfully set and access the Options fields 0 and 1 through the `NVP API` with the `GetTransactionDetails` method.

I am also able to set options fields 2 through 9 also in the initial transaction with my 3rd party shopping cart.

I am having trouble accessing fields 2 through 9 using the `API`, though I know they are making it through to paypal since I can see it in them in the Shopping Cart Contents details of the transaction in the interactive web interface.

Please assist with the API call that will return fields on`[2-9]/os[2-9]/L_OPTIONSNAME[2-9]/L_OPTIONSVALUE[2-9]` or however these should be referenced.

Comment: what is the actual code you're using?

Comment: I use simpleCart(js) to set the Options field and submit the shopping cart.

Comment: With the PayPal - API Explorer - specifically the GetTransactionDetailsRequest parameter, I can only see Options fields 0 and 1.  Is it correct that the API Explorer is utilizing the NVP?  Is there another way to retrieve Options 2 through 9?